# Check out Cart item without Tax on specific countries

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1

If I select the country as **Germany**, in Check out Cart, the product **costs 39,90** . This is the price with tax and it is correct.

but when I select the country as **Albania**, in Check out Cart, the product **costs 32,18** . This is the price without tax.

I need same tax for all countries

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Let us know the version of your magento.

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create tax rates for all countries. 
   Sales => Tax => Manage Tax Rate => Add tax rate.
2. Select all Tax rates in your Tax Rule.

Instead of creating tax rate manual, you can import all the tax rate through CSV, and Add it in your Rule.